# How to install GDB 8 in CentOS 7

Tags: linux, centos, gdb

I need to install GDB 8.0 or above in my CentOS 7. My current version of gdb is 7.6.1.

I have followed the guide at [devtoolset-7-gdb | Install HowTo](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-sclo-rh-testing-x86_64/devtoolset-7-gdb-8.0-17.el7.x86_64.rpm.html):

1. `yum install centos-release-scl-rh`
2. `yum --enablerepo=centos-sclo-rh-testing install devtoolset-7-gdb`

but when I hit `gdb -v`, I get my old version: `7.6.1` and not `8.0`.

Comment: Are you certain `devtoolset-7-gdb` is installing GDB 8? If it is GDB 8, then you need to source the new version of GDB at init. Also see [How to update Apache and PHP using SCL?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/412122) on U&L.SE. It is doing the same thing, but for Apache, Python and PHP.

Comment: have the same problem installed devtoolset-8 -gdb
but gdb --version give 7.6 , any solution ?

Comment: @AgnosticCucumber
ok i found the answer you need to enable SCL look here , i run it and its working 
https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/devtoolset-7/

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you to follow below mentioned steps, which have been referred from [here](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/devtoolset-7/).

Step 1. Install a package with repository for your system:

On CentOS, install package centos-release-scl available in CentOS repository:

```
sudo yum -y install centos-release-scl
```

On RHEL, enable RHSCL repository for you system:

```
sudo yum-config-manager --enable rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms
```

Step 2.
Install the collection:

```
sudo yum -y install devtoolset-7
```

Step 3.
Start using software collections:

```
scl enable devtoolset-7 bash
```